# How do you computed this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to calculate the following limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt(n)e^{-n^2(x-n^2)}$

So we need to consider three cases: $x=0, x>0, x<0$.

For $x=0$ the above limit becomes:
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt(n)e^{n^4}$
since $e^{n^4}$ is the dominant term here as ${n\to\infty}$, hence this quantity goes to $\infty$.

For $x>0$ the above limit becomes:
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt(n)e^{-n^2x+n^4}$. The dominant term of the exponent
is $n^4$, hence this quantity goes to $\infty$.

For $x<0$ the above limit becomes:
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt(n)e^{n^2x+n^4}$. The dominant term of the exponent
is $n^4$, hence this quantity goes to $\infty$.

I am not sure this is correct.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show what you know and what you've attempted so far?

Comment: I did edit my answer

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Okay thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you write $\sqrt(n)$ instead of simply writing $\sqrt n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand correctly your question is $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/2}e^{-n^2(x-n^2)}$. Rewrite: $$n^{1/2}e^{-n^2(x-n^2)} = e^{-n^2(x-n^2)+\frac{\ln(n)}{2}}$$ Now notice that $$-n^2(x-n^2)+\frac{\ln(n)}{2} = -xn^2+n^4+\frac{\ln(n)}{2}$$which is the exponent goes to infinity for all values of $x$ so $e$ to that exponent will also go to infinity as e is a continuous function so we can pull the limit inside. This of course depends on what theorems you have proved so far in class.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand how you transformed $n^{1/2}$ into $\frac{ln(n)}{2}$ @Lucas Bachmann

Comment: $n^{1/2}=e^{\ln (n^{1/2})}$ because they are inverse functions and $\ln(n^{1/2})=\frac12 \ln(n)$ by log rules

Comment: perfect thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative we have that, for any fixed $x$, eventually

$$-n^2(x-n^2) =n^4-xn^2 \ge n^4-\frac{n^4}2=\frac{n^4}2$$

therefore

$$\sqrt n \;e^{-n^2(x-n^2)}\ge \sqrt n \; (\sqrt e)^{n^4}\to \infty$$